# Why is webpack adding a different route name to a bundle with webpackChunkName

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm using the `webpackChunkName` comment in my router file (Vue.js + Webpack).

My router file has the following routes defined:

```
const HomePage = () => 
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "HomePage" */'@/views/home/HomePage.vue');
const PricingPage = () => 
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "PricingPage" */'@/views/pricing/PricingPage.vue');
```

When I load the homepage, I see it's also loading the pricing page chunk for some reason, and it's loading it as `HomePage~PricingPage.js`

Why is it loading it on the homepage? And why is it loading with that different name?

Comment: how does a src with `~` work?

Comment: Are you sure you are not including the pricing page anywhere else?

Comment: @T.Short yes, there's no import of the pricing page anywhere else (but the router), and no prefetch references either